# java Jsoup question how can i split by word?

Tags: java, jsoup

I want to get html content without tags and the result as

```
word
word
word
```

So I tried the following.

```
public class PreProcessing {

    public static void main(String\[\] args) throws Exception {

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("filename.txt");

        URL url = new URL("[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed\_computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_computing)");

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

        String inputLine = "";

        String input = "";


        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)

        {
            input += inputLine;
            //          System.out.println(inputLine);
        }

        //create Jsoup document from HTML

        Document jsoupDoc = Jsoup.parse(input);

        //set pretty print to false, so \\n is not removed

        jsoupDoc.outputSettings(new OutputSettings().prettyPrint(false));

        //select all <br> tags and append \\n after that

        //        [jsoupDoc.select](https://jsoupDoc.select)("br").after("\\\\n");

        //select all <p> tags and prepend \\n before that

        //        [jsoupDoc.select](https://jsoupDoc.select)("p").before("\\\\n");

        //get the HTML from the document, and retaining original new lines

        String str = jsoupDoc.html().replaceAll(" ", "\n");
        //        str.replaceAll("\t", "");

        String strWithNewLines = Jsoup.clean(str, "", Whitelist.none(), new OutputSettings().prettyPrint(false));
        strWithNewLines.replaceAll("\t", "\n");
        strWithNewLines.replaceAll("\\"", "");

        strWithNewLines.replaceAll(".", "");

        System.out.println(strWithNewLines);

        out.print(strWithNewLines);
    }
}
```

This is my code I tried `en.wiki~ distributed_computin`g and read from `BufferedReader` and use `jsoupDoc` and I want to replace word `" "` to `"\n"` because I want to `word \n word\n word\n` like this.

Then result is

```
Distributed

computing

-

Wikipedia                                               Distributed

computing                           From

Wikipedia,

the

free

encyclopedia                                                Jump

to

navigation              Jump

to

search              "Distributed

application"

redirects

here.

For

trustless

applications,

see
```

But I want result like this

```
Distributed

computing

-

Wikipedia

Distributed

computing

From

Wikipedia

the

free

encyclopedia

Jump

to

navigation

Jump

to

search

Distributed

application

redirects

here

For

trustless

applications

see
```

I tried like

```
strWithNewLines.replaceAll("\\"", "");

strWithNewLines.replaceAll(".", "");
```

But this did not work. Why didn't it work? I did googling but I can't found the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try this for the last few lines. This will bring you nearer to your desired result:

```
String strWithNewLines = Jsoup.clean ...;
String result = strWithNewLines.replaceAll("\t", "\n")
    .replaceAll("\"", "");
    //.replaceAll(".", "");

System.out.println(result);
```

The problem in your code is that String is immutable, so `String.replaceAll` will replace nothing in the original String, but produce a new one where the substitiution has been done. But you never use the result.

And there is a problem with `.replaceAll(".", "")`. This will give you an empty string, because `.` matches every character and it will be substituted by an empty string.